# How to display a message to a user using the name they entered

Tags: javascript

First post here and forgive me im still learning Javascript, basically, I want to take the name the user entered and display it in a welcome message written in HTML using temporal literals. The message will be on a separate page to the form input. Can anyone shed some light on this please, been trying for a while but cannot get it to work.

https://github.com/Gh0ul5lay3r-91/Family-Fun-Quiz

thats my repository for anyone who would like to help out.

Thanks in advance

Comment: hello, and welcome to stackoverflow, please post your code as a part of the question, otherwise it's very likely to be downvoted.

Answer (score 0):

I checked out your repository, the core issue is that you are switching the pages, and js kind of "**forgets**" what happens when you change pages.

1. You are collecting information on `index.html` page correctly... but you ask it to redirect it to `quiz.html` page. That's exactly when JS will clean up it's memory and will "forget" what you have entered in the page. So, either,
   a. display the result in the same page.
   b. pass the form-data to the next page using some server-side tech.
2. In your javascript file, `formCheck`, please review the logic there if you opt to display the result in the same page without redirect, then you can remove `form.submit()`.

A quick patch would be to remove `form.submit()`, copy over the content of `quiz.html` to `index.html` and removing `quiz.html`.

This won't be a 100% fix, but should put you in the right path.

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript will stop running when switching pages, so just use two scripts in two pages, `index.html` and `quiz.html`

You add a URL parameter when you load `quiz.html`, so just write a javascript in the page

```
window.onload = function() {
        welcomeName();
}

function welcomeName(){
    const queryString = window.location.search;
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(queryString);
    let userName = urlParams.get('full_name');
    let welcomeBox = document.getElementById('welcome-box');
    let welcomeMessage = `
    <h2>Welcome to the quiz ${userName}</h2>
    `;
    
    welcomeBox.innerHTML = welcomeMessage;
}
```

and delete the username display part of your `script.js`

```
let form = document.getElementById('signup-form');
form.addEventListener('submit', formCheck);

function formCheck(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    let name = document.getElementById('name').value;
    
    if(name === null || name === ""){
        alert('Please provide a name and email address');
        console.log("This is working");
    }else{
        form.submit();
    }
}
```